# DAX sub-total wrong when filtered by other filter

Tags: excel-2013, powerpivot, dax

I have a power pivot summarising sales data on various levels of hierarchy.

I have added a picture showing data structure and expanded examples to be more illustrative.

The data has products and countries.

[image: PICTURE WITH SAMPLE OF DATA]

My task is to return a "category total" of sales, which should respect all geographical filters, but ignore product filters.

This is the DAX I am using

```
Sales Total:=SUM([Volume])
```

(this measure is an explicit sum of original volume data field)

```
Category Totals:=
       CALCULATE( [Sales Total], 
                  ALL(TBL[brand], 
                      TBL[Sub-brand], 
                      TBL[SKU]
                     )
                  )
```

this is the measure where I'm trying to capture totals above product level - called "Category" because it sums up all products in a geographical set, be it a market, region, sub-region.

[PICTURE WITH MY RESULTS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AV7n.jpg)

Problem 1: when geographical field is filtered indirectly, sub-totals do not reflect that (i.e. market doesn't have for Brand 2).

Problem 2: if a product attribute (i.e. Brand) is higher in hierarchy of row fields than geographical (i.e. market etc), sub-totals on that level show a global total at all times instead of sub-totalling regions/markets that they belong to.

Comment: Supposing `[Volume]` is a measure, how is it being calculated? I see you have only one table with all your data, add additional details about the columns and applied filter in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: **Alejandro**, thank you for looking at this. I have changed the post, added a data sample and more illustrative results. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to post actual pictures, so you have to click on the link. I hope it's a little better - I spent 2 hours preparing this example :-))

Comment: Your measure uses All() against the Brand, the Sub-Brand and the SKU. This is telling the calculate to ignore the filters applied to those fields, so your Pivot 3 subtotals are ignoring the Brand filter and your Pivot 4 totals are including the figures for both brands in each total.

Comment: **Gordon K**, i sort of understand that - but I don't know how to make it work the way i need. Any tips on how to change that? Thank you! :)

Comment: Guys, the first problem - how to make it sum up only visible rows, regardless why the others may not be visible? Second, how to make brand sub-totals to include also only visible rows?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, any more thoughts? I've normally managed to solve all my troubles quite well with extensive research, but i' failing this one. Please let me know if i can give an additional info so you can help me. Thanks, Lana

Comment: @LanaB, what do you mean by ignore product filters? You want to ignore product filters but you also want your measure apply them when any product filter (brand, sub-brand, SKU) is selected, where do you want to ignore them?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, i mean that this measure should sum up total market, regardless how product attributes are filtered (or not filtered). But if the market is not visible in rows, I don't want it in sub-totals. In Pivot 3, Group 3 total still includes Brazil, although it's not displayed in rows. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I spent a weekend trying different combinations of various functions, and it appears, I needed to do is use either

```
NEW CAT TOTAL:= SUMX(VALUES(TBL[Market], [Category Totals])
```

where

```
Category Totals:=  CALCULATE( [Sales Total], 
              ALL(TBL[brand], 
                  TBL[Sub-brand], 
                  TBL[SKU]
                 )
              )
```

or adjust the Category Totals to an equivalent by adding VALUES of Market

```
Category Totals:=  CALCULATE( [Sales Total], 
              VALUES(TBL[Market],
              ALL(TBL[brand], 
                  TBL[Sub-brand], 
                  TBL[SKU]
                 )
              )
```

I don't understand why these work, but they do. I am grateful everyone who tried to help!

Comment: It is awesome when you find the answer by yourself, as a last try could you try this: `Category Totals = CALCULATE([Sales Total],ALLEXCEPT(TBL,TBL[Market],TBL[Sub-region],TBL[Region]))`

Comment: @alejandrozuleta sorry for a late reply - this was my original function, it wasn't working, but thank you. I do realise that i probably word my questions weirdly - I'll try better next time. Thank you for trying, L